# Ebooks for building game framework in HTML5

Tags: html5, assets

I begin to develop game but I don't know best ebooks for build simple game framework in HTML5 . Can anyone suggest ebooks for me and where to get free image resources for build map in game like as Contra, Super Mario, ... such as grass, characters, animals, monsters,...?

Comment: Questions such as this just generate lists. As you can see by the answers so far. Please read the [FAQ] to learn how to use this site. We're a QA site, so we value questions that have definitive answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this one and it really helped me up understand a lot of things and gae me the basics to start my own games:

[http://www.amazon.com/HTML5-Games-Creating-CSS3-WebGL/dp/1119975085/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1355543837&sr=1-1&keywords=html+5+games](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1119975085)

Answer (score 0):

For your second question, there are plenty of free resources out there.

http://opengameart.org has some good stuff, though some of it may have attribution licenses etc.

Here's a list of places for free art someone compiled, it seems to have something for everyone: http://letsmakegames.org/resources/art-assets-for-game-developers/